# How I Can Use The Get Value as A Slug

Tags: slug

in my single.php i took a data from one $_GET[] value and i'm using this like

**domain.com/example-slug/?holder=value**

The thing i want is **domain.com/example-slug/value** or **domain.com/example-slug/holder/value**

so, how i can to this?

Comment: What is this `holder` & what relation does it have with a single post? You don't have to get the value from `$_GET`. If the relation is clear, then perhaps you can achieve the same with a custom post type or taxonomy.

Comment: I have to use $_GET, i know ctp's or taxonomies. $_GET value call a data from custom meta box array.

Comment: you can use Rewrite API for your needs. You can create rewrite tags and rules for functionality. Check these page pls. https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: I know add_rewrite_rule and i search this, just i don't know how i can do this with that. This is the reason why i ask Serkan Bey :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything with rewrite rules.

Your example ("domain.com/example-slug/?holder=value") is a perfect example of "Plain" Permalinks. So your starting point is to set Permalinks (Settings > Permalinks) to something other than "Plain". This will take the "/?" component out of the URL, and generate a URL in your preferred format.

The second thing is to capture the URL, parse it and get the "value" (to use your words). You can do this with a function like the one below. Put this function in your functions.php (or a plugin if you prefer). Then call it on the page/post where you want to get the "value". The function will yield the "value" as a variable $myvalue. You can expand the function to do more stuff, or you could return the value elsewhere to do something with it.

```
function getslug(){

    // get the url
    $myurl = home_url( $wp->request );
    //echo "<p>The page url is ".$myurl." </p>";  //DEBUG

    // Explode the url to get access to the taxonomy and terms
    $pageterms = explode('/', $myurl);
    //echo "the exploded components of the URL <pre>";print_r($pageterms);echo "</pre>"; //DEBUG

    // the value is always the last element in the url, so we'll count the number of elements
    $mycount = count($pageterms);
    //echo "<p>The element count is ".$mycount." </p>";  //DEBUG

    // since array keys always start with zero, the key for the value will be the count minus 1 (to allow for the zero)
    $myvalue = $pageterms[$mycount-1];
    //echo "<p>My value is  ".$myvalue." </p>";  //DEBUG

}
```

**PS**: I've left my echo statements (used for Debugging) in this example; you can just delete them if you don't need/want them.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your URL using Rewrite rule like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^example-slug/value $ example-slug/?holder=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Right now htaccess is my last option, i'm trying to do this with Wordpress codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rewrite function filter to your "site specific functions plugin" or to theme's functions.php

After editing functions.php or activating your plugin you will need to **flush WP's rewrite rules**. Go to Admin Dashboard >Settings > Permalinks and click save (your new rules will then be applied)

Examples (not tested):

**For posts:**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: my post rewrite plugin
*/
function my_post_rules($rules)
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $my_rule = array(
      '(.+?)/(.+?)$' => 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&holder=$matches[2]'
// or
      'example-slug/(.+?)$' => 'index.php?category_name=example-slug&holder=$matches[1]'
    );
    return array_merge($my_rule, $rules);
}
add_filter('post_rewrite_rules', 'my_post_rules');
```

**For pages:**

```
function my_page_rules($rules)
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $my_rule = array(
      '(.+?)/(.+?)$' => 'index.php?page_name=$matches[1]&holder=$matches[2]'
// or
      'example-slug/(.+?)$' => 'index.php?page_name=' . 'example-slug&holder=$matches[1]'
    );
    return array_merge($my_rule, $rules);
}
add_filter('page_rewrite_rules', 'my_page_rules');
```

Use of WP's *[get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)* function in your template is probably unnecessary in your case, but it might be needed for "GET values" used in other circumstances. So it is a good habit to use *get_query_var* in your template and "declare" the query var via *[query_var filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars)*.